# Why does File.mkdirs() create two directories instead of one?

Tags: sd-card

This code should create a single directory:

```
 File[] dirs = context.getExternalFilesDirs(type);

 File dir = new File(dirs[dirs.length-1].getAbsolutePath());
 dir.mkdirs();

 return dir;
```

When I run it, it creates two directories:

1. `mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.test.sdcard`
2. `storage/0D68-5DA2/Android/data/com.test.sdcard`

Why are both of these created?

It is important that I only have 1 directory.

Comment: You need to add a tag for the language you're using, and show us the actual contents of `dirs` - preferably as a [mcve] - read that for some advice that will improve your chances of helpful answers.

Comment: Have you checked that they are actually different directories (and not merely different names that refer to the *same* directory?)